# Semantic Media Wiki: Displaying a SVG element of a HTML page

Tags: html, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, semantic-mediawiki

I have a HTML page that displays a SVG element (a Business process diagram) using some javascript libraries. A String variable, say 'str' needs to be given to html function.

After reading [this](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/How_to_write_a_JavaScript_to_display_data_in_a_Semantic_MediaWiki), I plan to use widgets. So far I understand that I need to copy all scripts to Widgets: Test. For creating the hook, I write

```
 {{#widget:Test|str=UserTask_1}}
```

The problem is that UserTask_1 is a variable as well. It is different each time.

Can someone help how can I add this dynamic information to my hook? This hook is a hyperlink from a previous page. In the previous page, I send the str=UserTask_1 through JavaWiki Bot.

PS: I have come-across SMW for first time. Please excuse if my language is not very technical at the moment.
Thanks.

Comment: How is the variable UserTask_1 stored? Is it a SMW property? Or an argument to a template?

Comment: I give it as an argument to a template.

Comment: Then can't you just pass it on? `{{#widget:Test|str={{{UserTask_1|some default text}}} }}`